# How to consume WCF Web Service in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, wcf

I have a  c# .NET 4.0 WCF webservice on my server. Some of php websites of customer are using my web service. We have changed our firewall and now the web service is not working anymore for the customer. The customer gets an empty array.

I would like to create some php site/page and implement some code to do a request to my wcf webservice. Can someone tell me how or give me some website link?

This is for example my wcf webservice url:

> https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I have found the nusoap library with a lot of examples. Here is my code which is working in my local test environment (XAMP):

```
$client = new nusoap_client('https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl', 'wsdl');
$client -> setCredentials("testusername","testpassword","basic");

$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->decode_utf8 = false;

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}


$result = $client->call('HelloWorld');

echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I have add this solution on the production environment and get this error:

Getting https://service.mycompany.com/SecurityService.svc?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to service.mycompany.com:443